# Give db_Execute to existing role

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I have created a role named "MasterData" but don't know how to give "db_execute" to it. Please guide

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean under "db_execute"?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? It gives examples too, and they're very easy to understand.

Comment: May be you need something like https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2011/04/sql-server-grant-execute-on-all-stored-procedures.html

Comment: Already went through the above links, they give examples on how to create db_execute and how to give this role to the user. But I want to give db_execute to MasterData role. When I gave "MasterData" role to a user, they were not able to execute the procedure, have to give "db_execute" seperataly

Answer (score 0):

Permissions for a given user are cumulative, including all permissions granted/denied directly to the user and those inherited from their role membership(s).

If you don't want to add individual users to your db_execute role, add the MasterData role to the db_execute role. MasterData role members will then have permissions granted/denied to db_execute too.

```
ALTER ROLE db_execute
    ADD MEMBER MasterData;
```